# Android Studio BottomNavigationView icon problem

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm using the `BottomNavigationView` for my app. All cool, but when I have more than 3 items, the items move on click.

I mean, the selected item, get more border, and the others unselected an item, move away, sticking together.

But my idea is a navigation menu, like Instagram. If I click an item of my navigation menu, all the items stay still and not start moving left or right.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of BottomNavigationView has condition: when there is more than 3 items then use shift mode.
so to disable this effect you have to add this line of code to your BottomNavigationView XML

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

PS : You need support library 28.0.0 and above

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly, you should add this to the dimensions file:**

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">10sp</dimen>
```

**Then, apply for each item in the bar:**

```
@SuppressLint("PrivateResource")
fun BottomNavigationView.fixSelectedItem(position: Int) {
    val bottomMenu = this.getChildAt(0) as? BottomNavigationMenuView
    val item = bottomMenu?.getChildAt(position) as? BottomNavigationItemView
    item?.let {
        val activeLargeLabel = it.findViewById<TextView>(com.google.android.material.R.id.largeLabel)

        if (activeLargeLabel != null && activeLargeLabel is TextView) {
            activeLargeLabel.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
            activeLargeLabel.ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.END
        }
    }
}
```

> **NOTE:** this names `design_bottom_navigation_` and `com.google.android.material.R` might be different in
>   `Support Legacy` libs. This is from`AndroidX`.

This is workaround how to fix that scale effect.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this for  showing both text and icons on BottomNevigationView for 3 to 5 items and stop shifting.

```
 app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

But you will will face a problem of long text cutting on BottmNevigationView for 5 items. for that ,I found a good solutions for stop shifting of text as well as icons of BottomNevigationView. You can also stop shifting of text as well as Icons on BottomNevigationView also. Snipshots of code is given here.

**1. Add this some line of code in BottomNevigationView as shown**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/seventy_dp"
    android:layout_semitransparent="true"
    android:background="@color/colorBottomNev"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
```

**2. Add Menu Items like as follows:-**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_catalogue"
        android:icon="@drawable/catalogue"
        android:title="@string/catalogue"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contracts"
        android:icon="@drawable/contract"
        android:title="@string/contracts"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_prospects"
        android:icon="@drawable/prospect"
        android:title="@string/prospects"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_performance"
        android:icon="@drawable/performance"
        android:title="@string/performance"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_advance"
        android:icon="@drawable/advance"
        android:title="@string/advance"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

**3.Add this style in style.xml  file:**

```
 <style name="BottomNavigationViewTextStyle">
            <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montmedium</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
            <item name="android:duplicateParentState">true</item>
            <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
            <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        </style>
```

**4)Add these in Dimen folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">10sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I got help from these  [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView) and [link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/139) .You can also get get help by studying these links.This helps me a lot.Hope this also help you. Thanks....

Comment: nice copy paste from my answer ;)

Comment: @YaroslavOvdiienko No sir, I don't copy it.I actually copy from my file.I forget to add these steps here.Yes this the way to overcome this iussues.